# Angular2 ngOnInit subscribe not execute function

Tags: angular, components

I have a problem, In My angular2 project, I have 2 Components and 1 Service. The function that setting the value in the Service  is working, but the function in the Child Component (who suscribe and get the data) never fired.

Additional Information:

- I use the `<router-outlet>` tag to load the Child component.
- The problem is in the Child Component .suscribe function

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { IStage, ISystemModule } from './board/board.component';
@Injectable()
export class DetailBoardService {
  //Observable ISystemModule source
  private activeModuleSource = new Subject<ISystemModule>();
  //Observable ISystemModule stream
  activeModuleObject$ = this.activeModuleSource.asObservable();
  //Service message commands
  setActiveModule(activeModule: ISystemModule) {
    console.log('Entro al Service:', activeModule);
    this.activeModuleSource.next(activeModule);
  }
  constructor() { }

}
```

Parent Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DetailBoardService } from '../detail-board.service';
declare var window;

export interface IStage {
  name: string,
  url: string,
}
export interface ISystemModule {
  name: string,
  icon: string,
  stages: Array<IStage>,
  mainViewUrl: string,
  active?: boolean
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-board',
  templateUrl: './board.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./board.component.css'],
  providers: [DetailBoardService]
})

export class BoardComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "WS Composer";
  ver = "v.0.1";
  releaseType = "Alpha";
  systemModules: Array<ISystemModule>;
  @Input() activeModule: ISystemModule;
  titleModal = "";
  contentModal = "";

  constructor(private router: Router, private detailBoardService: DetailBoardService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //POPULATE SYSTEM MODULES
    this.systemModules = [
      { name: "Frontend", icon: "fa fa-eye", mainViewUrl: "board/frontend", stages: [{ name: "VIEWS", url: "fviews" }, { name: "CONTROLLERS", url: "fcontrollers" }, { name: "SERVICES", url: "fservices" }, { name: "COMPONENTS", url: "fcomponents" }, { name: "SAVE & PUBLISH", url: "fpublish" }], active: true },
      { name: "Backend", icon: "fa fa-cog", mainViewUrl: "board/backend", stages: [{ name: "MODEL", url: "bmodel" }, { name: "CONTROLLERS", url: "bcontrollers" }, { name: "ROUTES", url: "broutes" }, { name: "STANDALONE MODULES", url: "bmodules" }, { name: "SAVE & PUBLISH", url: "bpublish" }] }
    ]
    this.activeModule = this.systemModules[0];
    console.log('seteo activeModule', this.activeModule);
    this.detailBoardService.setActiveModule(this.activeModule);
  }

  public selectModule(index: number) {

    for (let module of this.systemModules) {
      module.active = false;
    }
    this.systemModules[index].active = true;
    this.activeModule = this.systemModules[index];
    this.detailBoardService.setActiveModule(this.activeModule);
    this.router.navigate([this.systemModules[index].mainViewUrl]);


    /*setTimeout(() => {
      window.$('ul.tabs').tabs();
    }, 200);*/

  }


}
```

Child Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ISystemModule, IStage } from '../board/board.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { DetailBoardService } from '../detail-board.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-backend',
  templateUrl: './backend.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./backend.component.css'],
  providers: [DetailBoardService]
})
export class BackendComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() activeModule: ISystemModule;
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private router: Router, private detailBoardService: DetailBoardService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.detailBoardService.activeModuleObject$.subscribe(
      activeModule => { //this function never firing!!!
        console.log('que trae:', activeModule);
        this.activeModule = activeModule;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
    console.log(this.activeModule);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Please help me

Comment: No helpful errors in the console that you forgot to include?

Comment: Nope, all is working, the sucribe never fired, I know because the console log inside the function never execute, but the outside (the ngOnInit console log) is working.and the value is undefined, and in the .html the {{activeModule}} not showing nothing.

Comment: Why are you assigning the subscribe to `this.subscription`? Have you tried it without that? So, instead of `this.subscription = this.detailBoardService.activeModuleObject$.subscribe...`, it would be `this.detailBoardService.activeModuleObject$.subscribe...`

Comment: I use this.subscription due to unsuscribe the object when destroy the component ( In angular page says that prevent possible memory leak  ) https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service  I got the same result if not assign to `this.subscription`

Comment: Yea, I realized that after I walked away to do something else for a few minutes. Sorry. At least, now we know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that when I put the Service in the component itself, Angular creates different instances for the class, so, the answer was: remove the providers array from both components and put the provider array in the ngmodule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BoardComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    FrontendComponent,
    BackendComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    LostpassComponent,
    ModalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, DetailBoardService)
  ],
  providers: [DetailBoardService], <-- HERE !!!
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Too funny! I was trying to repro this, and I couldn't. That was the only difference between my code and yours. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: tnanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Thank you! This just saved me some time working with a project I inherited - I didn't even notice that the provides were per component instead of in the app module. This caused issues for me with Angular 7.